# How to get current `topMostItemindex` for `react-virtuoso`?

Tags: reactjs, react-virtuoso

I want to persist the scroll position of my `<Virtuoso />` list through unmounts/remounts.

I think I want to use the [`initialTopMostItemIndex`](https://virtuoso.dev/initial-index/) property to restore my previous scroll position in order to achieve this - [this post](https://github.com/petyosi/react-virtuoso/issues/47#issuecomment-545778663) makes me believe this is better than scrolling imperatively post-render.

But how can I get the current `topMostItemIndex`, so I can save it and restore it later?

I use Virtuoso in a manner similar to [this playground](https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-bouman-hj7pwf?file=/App.js):

```js
<Virtuoso
   style={{ height: 400 }}
   data={generateUsers(1000)}
   ref={ref}
   itemContent={(index, user) => (
      <div>
        <h4>
            {user.index}. {user.name}
        </h4>
        <div style={{ marginTop: "1rem" }}>{user.description}</div>
      </div>
   )}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Recently I added a method called `getState` that is paired with the `restoreStateFrom` property.

[Check the example](https://github.com/petyosi/react-virtuoso/blob/493172cf04ae8c54a6a4afdfebd568a0a7679746/examples/state.tsx#L27).